# Stuck in infinite recursive loop (DFS)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search, shortest-path

I am trying to solve a shortest path algorithm problem using a knight on a chess board. I understand that BFS (breadth first search) is the most efficient approach but I want to try and solve it using DFS (Depth first search) first. Understanding both algorithms will greatly help my knowledge.
**Issue/Problem**: My `nextMove(curRow, curCol, moves)` function eventually stack overflows. The base case of my function works because I can see the first stacks return successfully. But as it gets towards the end of possible scenarios it runs infinitely with the same array values.
**What I expected**: I expect the recursive function to exit when there are no more scenarios left
**What I've tried**: I tried to pop the array when the recursive function returns so it does not keep trying with the same array values.
**Code**: https://jsfiddle.net/mschreider/jaqL1c5d/ *uncomment line 115 to run*
I commented out the console.log() function call because of the stack overflow problem.

```js
function knightMoves(start, finish) {

  let shortestPath = []
  
    function nextMove(curRow, curCol, moves) {
        //console.log(moves)
            if (curRow === finish[0] && curCol === finish[1]) {
            if (shortestPath.length === 0) {
                shortestPath = moves
            }
            else {  
                shortestPath = moves.length < shortestPath.length ? moves : shortestPath
            }

            console.log(shortestPath)
        
            return
        }
    
        // coordinates the knight can move [row, col]
        let options = [[1,2], [1,-2], [-1,2], [-1,-2], [2,1], [2,-1], [-2,1], [-2,-1]]
        for (let i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
            let moveRow = options[i][0]
            let moveCol = options[i][1]

            let newRow = curRow + moveRow
            let newCol = curCol + moveCol
            
            let proceed = validMove(newRow, newCol, moves)
            
            // if there is space to move, move knight
            if (proceed) {
                let arr = [...moves]
                arr.push([newRow, newCol])
                nextMove(newRow, newCol, arr)
                arr.pop()
            }
        }    
        return 
    }   

    nextMove(start[0], start[1], [start])
    return shortestPath
}

function validMove(row, col, moves) {
    // Check if the location has already been seen
  let coordinate = [row, col]
    let newSpot = true
    if (moves.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i <moves.length; i++) {
      let seen = moves[i].length === coordinate.length && moves[i].every((value, index) => value === coordinate[index])
      if (seen) {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    newSpot = true
  }
  
  // Check if the knight has space to move
  if (newSpot) {
    if ((row >= 0 && row < 8) && (col >= 0 && col < 8)) {
      return true
    }
    else {
      //debugger;
      return false
    }
  }
}

// console.log(knightMoves([0,0],[3,3]))
```

Comment: Please see [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992).

Comment: @ScottSauyet added. But it is not functional because of my stack overflow issue

Comment: I don't know if it would help much given the numbers that Trincot posted, but one optimization that should help a lot is to stop visiting any path when its length exceeds the length of the currently shortest path.  Still, breadth-first seems much more likely to help.

Comment: The snippet is often useful in this case because the user can simply copy it into an answer for quick fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

- Your `shortestPath` array gets mutated by `arr.pop()`. When the recursive call that found the target returns, `arr` is the array reference that is now shared with `shortestPath`. This means that after the depth-first algorithm would complete, you wouldn't have the answer. This can be fixed by not doing the `pop` (it doesn't serve a purpose as `arr` is not used after that) or not taking a copy of the array where you do it now, but `push/pop` with `moves`, and take a copy at the moment you assign to `shortestPath`: that way you ensure `shortestPath` will never be mutated by a `push` or `pop` afterwards.
- The depth-first traversal will visit **all** possible move sequences (that do not revisit a previous square on the path). This number of sequences is too large for any computer to visit in any reasonable time. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Brute-force_algorithms) gives an estimation of 10<sup>51</sup> distinct move sequences on an 8x8 board. That's more than there are water molecules in the oceans. In your algorithm the sequences that run **via** the target square are not visited, but that still amounts to an astronomical number of sequences to visit. You can safely forget about that traversal completing in your lifetime.

Your algorithm is what is called "brute force". For 5x5 it will work in a reasonable time, but it quickly gets out of control for greater boards. Although there are some ways to optimise your algorithm, depth-first is not the right tool for this.

If you want to consider a better alternative for breadth-first, then look into A*, which is an "informed" search, in the category of [best-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search) algorithms, based on a heuristic. Except for positions that are nearby, a good heuristic in this case is the Euclidean distance between the two positions divided by √3.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the first issue. I did not realize the shallow copy was the reason the final array was being mutated. I will now try to implement this using BFS.

Comment: While that Wikipedia article is clearly related, note that this is not a full Knight's Tour problem.  We need to get from A to B, not cover every square on the board.

Answer (score 0):

If it runs forever, the exit condition must be at fault.

So ... what's supposed to exit the recursion? `nextMove` recurses while `validMove` returns `true`. `validMove` returns `false` in two cases:

1. the knight tries to move outside the board. By itself, this doesn't guarantee termination, because the knight can walk in circles.
2. the knight visits a coordinate he has already visited in this path

The latter ensures that the path length is at most 64 (because otherwise a square would be visited twice), so we are considering at most 8**64 paths. That's up to 6277101735386680763835789423207666416102355444464034512896 paths. Granted, the vast majority of these will leave the board at some point, but if even a tiny fraction remain inside the boundaries, this might take forever.

To investigate whether this really is the issue, let's restrict path lengths, and output the number of paths considered, by inserting the following into validMove:

```
  if (moves.length == maxPathLength) {
    visitedPaths++
    return false;
  }
```

and running this with various values for maxPathLength:

| maxPathLength | visitedPaths |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 16 |
| 4 | 288 |
| 10 | 2509424 |
| 12 | 42251728 |
| 13 | 161594928 |
| 14 | 648090800 |
| 15 | 2359955136 |

So even just looking a paths of length 15, we are visiting over a billion paths, and the digits keep piling up! There is no way we'll be able to visit every path of length 64 (and such paths exist!) in our lifetime!

So your algorithm is beyond redemption. You need to find a way to exit early, and focus on the solutions you want rather than trying to iterate through the entire solution space. And since you seek the shortest path, processing shorter paths first rather than going down into the rabbit hole is what you need. In other words: breadth first, rather than depth first traversal.

Comment: I can see how quickly this can become unattainable. I was able to get my algo working with a smaller sized board, but breadth first makes much more sense.